# new to .htaccess, how to redirect specific page to mainpage

Tags: .htaccess

I'm new to .htaccess file.

My site is hosted on 1and1 and by default it shows www.mydomain.com/defaultsite when nothing is uploaded to my account. Now I've uploaded my wp site and have managed to make it go to index, but if someone inputs in the url www.domain.com/defaultsite he will still get the wrong place.

How can I manage this issue with .htaccess file so that any request to defaultsite will take the user to www.mydomain.com ?

Comment: I had a similar problem. I am not sure it is the same so I created [web hosting - Site hosted with 1and1 redirects to defaultsite - Webmasters Stack Exchange](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/103640/site-hosted-with-1and1-redirects-to-defaultsite/103641).

Answer (score 0):

I'm not a 1and1 user, but this could be a DNS cache issue. First, check your document root for the presence of a directory called `defaultsite`. If it exists, remove it. If not, then you can attempt removing it using `mod_rewrite`. Insert this rule immediately after `RewriteEngine On` in your `.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteRule ^defaultsite/?$ http://yourdomain.com/ [R=302,L]
```

If it's working for you, you can safely change 302 to 301 to make in permanent and cache-able.

I have also seen comments referring to an `index.html` file in the document root. If you see one, delete it - it could be that, internally, 1and1 maps `defaultsite` to `index.html`.

Also, it will help for you to clear the cache in your browser when testing. If using Chrome, you can open the Developer Tools (Ctrl+Shift+I), click on the settings cog at the top right of the panel that opens, and check 'Disable cache (while DevTools is open)`.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue and was pulling out my hair trying to figure this out. 1&1 is hosting while Namecheap holds my domain. I was able to access my page without /defaultsite on Safari and mobile Chrome. But on desktop Chrome I was being redirected to /defaultsite.

To remedy this I cleared my cache, flushed my DNS cache, and cleared my browsing history. Not sure if the latter 2 were necessary but having done all three it did help resolve this issue.